# MySQL: Rows to Columns dynamically

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL database with these tables:

table products:

```
+-------------+
| id          |
+-------------+
| 1           |
| 2           |
+-------------+
```

table attribute_values:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| product_id  | key      | value     |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 1           | title    | Orange    |
| 1           | code     | O125      |
| 2           | title    | Pizza     |
| 2           | code     | O138      |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

And I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT  products.id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN attribute_values.key = 'title' THEN attribute_values.value END) title,
        MAX(CASE WHEN attribute_values.key = 'code' THEN attribute_values.value END) code
FROM    products JOIN attribute_values ON products.id = attribute_values.product_id
GROUP   BY products.id;
```

With this output:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| id          | title    | code      |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 1           | Orange   | 0125      |
| 2           | Pizza    | O138      |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like the script to generate one column for each distinct value of attribute_values.key without explicitly specifying the keys (title and code in this case).

i.e. pseudoscript:

```
SELECT  products.id
generate column foreach distinct attribute_values.key
FROM    products JOIN attribute_values ON products.id = attribute_values.product_id
GROUP   BY products.id;
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

Thanks for any efforts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating dynamic pivot tables for dynamic values you need to write dynamic sql something as

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when a.`key` = ''',
      a.`key`,
      ''' then value end) AS ',
      a.`key`
    )
  ) into @sql
from attribute_values a ;

set @sql = concat('select p.id, ', @sql, ' from products p
                  join attribute_values a on a.product_id = p.id
                  group by p.id
');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2224f/1